# Launching Resources for my aws Pipeline into a VPC, got Resource not healthy: TERMINATED

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have used aws data pipeline to execute my bash shell tasks without any problems, in this case, aws data pipeline uses default EC2 instance to execute my bash shell works.

Right now, I want to use aws data pipeline to connect my customized EC2instance ( vpc ) without using aws default EC2 instance to run my shell tasks by following the following two links, but got error :"Resource not healthy: TERMINATED" ( failureReason )

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-how-task-runner-user-managed.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-resources-vpc.html

Based on aws document (step 4): Task Runner connects to the AWS Data Pipeline web service using HTTPS. If you are using an AWS resource, ensure that HTTPS is enabled in the appropriate routing table and subnet ACL. If you are using a firewall or proxy, ensure that port 443 is open.

Do I need to run a small HTPPS service ( dummy is fine ) on my customized EC2 instance machine?. The aws document is not clear about it.

Any suggestions, advice will be appreciated greatly!!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution by trying this: just opening port 80 to secure group too on my customized EC2 ( vpc ) instance. Now data pipeline can connect my customized EC2 and worked well:)